# How to Resend/Forward email as it was comming from the mailbox that resend´s it - Outlook/Exchange Online

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

I have 2 scenarios of rules that I need to work similar, but only needs one of them to work:

1: Resend an email that arrives in the mailbox of *firstreceiver@domain.com* from i.e. *sender@domain.com*, but where when it arrives in *finalreceiver@domain.com* it should look like it is comming from *firstreceiver@domain.com* and not *sender@domain.com* - at the moment I am only able to resend it like it seems to come from *sender@domain.com*, and that is not what I need

2: Forward an email that arrives in inbox of *firstreceiver@domain.com*, but without the "FW:" in subject and without the pre-appended Header that normally is in a Forwarded E-mail.

Is there a way (plugin, script or something) that can help me solve this?

I have looked for plugins and scripts that can help me do this, but so far only found plugins for On-Prem Exchange, not Exchange Online.

Hope someone can help. :-)

Br

Stig

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook desktop you can create a VBA macro where you can handle incoming emails. The `NewMailEx` event is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example,`MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

In the `NewMailEx` event handler you may check the incoming emails whether you need to forward it to another mailbox and, if required, you can set up all the required properties on the forwarded item created by [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) method. Then you can set up the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which indicates the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. Be aware, you need to set up permissions in Exchange to be able to send on behalf of another person.

You can also change the `Subject` property to remove any prefixes. As well as edit the message body before sending the item. Use the `HTMLBody` property for dealing with a message body. Finally, the `Send` method submits the item.

If you are not familiar with VBA syntax yet, take a look at the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev .. But how will you use VBScript on a Outlook 365 Online App and on Exchange Online? (We are not using On-Prem nor PC Installed Outlook) .. I have GA access to Exchange Server so have full access to the Exchange and Tennent.

Comment: That is not clear from your post above.

Comment: Try using PowerApps instead.

Comment: I mention it both In the Headline and In the last part of my post that it is Exchange Online .. however, using PowerShell, if that is possible, Can you give me some pointers In the right Direction?

Comment: The online Exchange mode exists in Outlook, so it was not clear. As I wrote earlier, take a look at PowerApps instead.